# why there is difference in address but still pointing to the same data?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<string.h>

struct node {
  int data;
  struct node * next;
};

int main() {

  struct node * head = (struct node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  head -> data = 10;

  head -> next = (struct node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  head -> next -> data = 20;

  head -> next -> next = NULL;

  int noOfNodes = 2;

  char * buff = malloc(50);

  strncpy(buff, (char * ) & noOfNodes, sizeof(int));
  // strncpy(buff+4,(char *)head,sizeof(struct node *));
  memcpy(buff + 4, (char * ) head, sizeof(struct node * ));

  printf("noOfNodes: %d\n\n", *(int * ) buff);

  printf("1]<%p><%d>\n", head, head -> data);
  printf("2]<%p><%d>\n\n", ((struct node * ) buff + 4), ((struct node * )(buff + 4)) -> data);

  printf("address of next node \n");

  printf("3]<%p>\n", head -> next);
  printf("4]<%p>\n", ((struct node * )(buff + 4)) -> next);

  return 0;
}
```

Ouput:

```
noOfNodes: 2

1]<0x56450bd632a0><10>
2]<0x56450bd63320><10>

address of next node 
3]<0x56450bd632c0>
4]<(nil)>
```

why there is difference in address ?

1] ends with ...2a0

2] ends with ...320

if address is different then how come it pointing to the variable data(...->data) correctly ?

why is (buff+4)->next is NULL? it should be same as head->next (i.e. <0x56450bd632c0>).

```
struct node *n1 = head;
```

when we do this irrespective of how large the struct node this only needs 8bytes to store(as we are storing address of struct node).

i want to do this using `memcpy()` (using only 8 bytes)store only the address of `struct node head` and not all `struct node` in (buff+4).
how to do this ? thats why i used (`struct node *`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[tl;dr]*   To copy the entire `*head` to `buff+4` the `memcpy` line needs to be changed as follows.

```
memcpy(buff+4, (char *)head, sizeof(struct node));  // instead of sizeof(struct node *)
```

With OP's code, assuming the likely case of 32b integers and 64b pointers:

- `struct node` is padded to satisfy the pointer alignment requirements

  ```
  struct node
  {
  int data;
  int hidden_padding_field;  // <--- inserted by the compiler
  struct node *next;
  };
  ```
- the following copies 8 bytes from `head` to `buff+4`, meaning `head->data` and `hidden_padding_field` get copied, but `head->next` does not.

  ```
  memcpy(buff+4, (char *)head, sizeof(struct node *));
  ```

Consequently, the `data` value gets copied correctly, but the `next` pointer is left unitialized. That it happens to be NULL is entirely by accident, just one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanx, now both .... ->next is same. what is OP's code ?

Comment: @temp1284 That's your code. Here "OP" stands for "original poster", or sometimes "original post".

Comment: @temp1284 To copy the `head` *pointer*, use `memcpy(buff+4, &head, sizeof(struct node *));`.

Comment: `head` has a type (`struct node *`) when we say `head` it means address of (`struct node`)
and `&head` means address of pointer (`struct node *`).
what i want is address of `struct node`, which is `head` (not `&head`);

Comment: @temp1284 What you get in my last comment *is* the address of the `struct node` that `head` points to. `head` is a pointer variable, its value is the address of a `struct node`, and that value is stored at address `&head`. So `memcpy(buff+4, &head, sizeof(struct node *));` will copy to `buff+4` the value of `head` which is the address of the `struct node` you `malloc`'d for it.

Comment: It is the same as `*(struct node **)(buff+4) = head;`, if you find that easier to follow.

Comment: how to get address of variable `head`? what i though is `&head` will do that.

Comment: @temp1284 The address of variable `head` is `&head` indeed. Not sure why (or perhaps what) you are asking, though.

Answer (score 2):

> why there is difference in address ?

Because the `buff` array is a different chunk of memory from the one that was `malloc`ed for the `head`, so `buff+4` is a different place in memory.

> if address is different then how come it pointing to the variable data(...->data) correctly ?

Because you `memcpy`d some memory into the `buff` at that location, copying it from the memory that `head` points at. So although it is a different chunk of memory, it has the same data written into it.

> why is (buff+4)->next is NULL?

Because you did not copy *enough* memory, so the part where the `next` member should be is still whatever was in that part of the `buff` before the copy. This happened because you told `memcpy` to copy as much memory as a `struct node *` takes up; but you didn't want to copy a chunk of memory that was a pointer, you wanted to copy a chunk of memory that was the node itself. So it should have said `sizeof(struct node)` instead of `sizeof(struct node *)`.

The `struct node` structure starts with `int data`, and `int` *might* be the same size as any *ordinary* pointer (at least, I can't think of any situations where it would be *bigger*). So when we look at the memory that starts at the location `buff + 4`, it seems we copied enough data there to put the correct value into the `->data`, but not enough to do anything about the `->next`.